# SSIS Как просуммировать весь столбец, разбитый на несколько файлов?

Tags: sql-server, integration-services

Есть несколько flat файлов, хочу соответственно объединить в их один и посчитать сумму по столбцу, результат записать в базу.
Получился только вариант, если через foreach loop container объединить все в одну temp таблицу, записать её во временную таблицу в бд и уже в следующем блоке считать все от туда и суммировать. Мне такое решение кажется не совсем правильным, не хотелось бы использовать лишние таблицы в базе, тем более для подобных операций.
Подскажите, наверняка есть альтернативные решения?

Answer (score 1):

В DataFlow есть элемент "Union All".Как раз позволяет объединить несколько FlatFileSource.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но если у меня этих flat файлов 30 и они с разными именами? В моем случае не совсем подходит, все их не будешь прописывать постоянно.

Answer (score 0):

Если не хочется делать 30 `Flat File Source`, то можно в цикле читать файлы и писать их в `Raw File Destination`, затем читать из него в Data Flow Task. `Raw File` пишется и читается очень быстро.
При этом в цикле подменять путь и название файла в `Flat File Source` можно через Property Expression.

Но - структура файлов у вас должна быть строго одинакова!